# Fatal Error: Found Nil While Unwrapping Optional Value TableViewCell to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I don't know what's happening.  Need help with either segue, didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or casting.  I have a tableview on top of a uiviewcontroller with a custom tableviewcell.  I successfully got an 4 arrays of Strings to present themselves in the custom cell.  Now I'm trying to pass this information to another uiviewcontroller.  I'm creating a public Int as....

```
var selectedVideoIndex: Int!
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath is.....

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

        let cell = self.resultsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultsTableViewCell

        let newIndexPath = resultsTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
        selectedVideoIndex = newIndexPath.row
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("playerSegue", sender: self)


    }
```

and prepareForSegue is.....

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "playerSegue"
        {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! VideoViewController

            controller.vidTitleLBL.text = self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex]
            controller.videoId = self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex]

        }
    }
```

Also I'm manually creating segue in storyboard. Should I do it from cell to the new controller or from the view?  Thanks.

****New****

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    selectedVideoIndex = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seguePlayer", sender: self)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultsTableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.videoTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = self.videoDescription[indexPath.row]
    cell.descriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    let url = NSURL(string: self.videoIMG[indexPath.row])
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    cell.videoImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

    return cell

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "seguePlayer"
        {

            print(self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex])
            print(self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex])
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! VideoViewController
            controller.vidTitleLBL.text = self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex]
            controller.videoId = self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex]

        }
    }
```

Got it to successfully print.  Now giving error casting at..

```
controller.vidTitleLBL.text = self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex]
            controller.videoId = self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex]
```

What do think this is??  Thank for the printing suggestion btw.

Comment: Hey Charles - Did you print out what the outputs are for self.videoTitle[selectedVideoIndex] and self.videoId[selectedVideoIndex]?

Comment: Just did.  It gave back error at...'let newIndexPath = resultsTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!'    It says I'm not getting back an indexPath to start with.   Any suggestions

Comment: would you mind posting the rest of your code in that file you're working in? that would be more helpful in detecting the issue.

Comment: When you created a segue you should be making a connection for the tableview cell to the new controller and not from the view.  How do you have it now?

Comment: check which class is the sender object.  Is it your custom tableview cell or something else

Comment: Please see new additions....Now I got casting problems.

Comment: What are those printed values for both in console? That will most likely lead you to your answer. Paste them in comments if you don't mind.

Comment: Do you actually need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath?  prepareForSegue will be called by you creating a segue in the storyboard.  I could be wrong though. You can get the index path inside the prepareforsegue.

Comment: Here is my console info...Wonder Girls (원더걸스) - NOBODY (Kor. Ver)
QZBn1e9pr2Q
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)  ....Which is a Youtube title and videoId.  They are unwrapped should I cast them "as! String"??

Answer (score 1):

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` already passes the `indexPath` so you should not create a cell in that delegate:

```
selectedVideoIndex = indexPath.row
```

should be enough, remove the cell code .

Or better way in `prepareForSegue` use:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRows()
```

then use that `indexPath`

```
print(self.videoTitle[indexPath.row])
print(self.videoId[indexPath.row])
```